# ng-model with bracket

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was looking through a code and i ran across this line of code and couldn't figure it out.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Search :</td>
        <td><input ng-model="query[queryBy]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Search By :</td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model="queryBy">
                <option value="name">NAME</option>
                <option value="company">COMPANY</option>
                <option value="designation">DESIGNATION</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees | filter:query">
            <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.company}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.designation}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

What does the [queryBy] mean in query[queryBy] ?

The JS:

```
$scope.query = {};
$scope.queryBy = '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input ng-model="query[queryBy]" />
```

This input will display the attribute that is the value of ***queryBy*** in the object ***query***.

For example,

```
$scope.query = {
    name: "someName",
    company: "someCompany",
    designation: "someDesignation"
};
```

then when the user selects NAME, the input will display *someName*.

If the user selects COMPANY, the input will display *someCompany*.

If the user selects DESIGNATION, the input will display *someDesignation*.

**UPDATE**

The point is that **query** is used in the filter below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in employees | filter:query">
    <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.company}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.designation}}</td>
</tr>
```

It is going to be used like this. The user types the keyword for the search and selects type of query that the user wants to search, then the query object will be used in the filter so that the data will display accordingly.

Comment: So the ng-model would become name when NAME is selcted?

Comment: it would be query[name], which will be "someName".

Comment: Please see the update in the answer, and if it solves the problem please accept it.

Comment: Would u mind looking at my prev qn and see if you could help me? please

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772036/angularjs-filter-search-based-on-option-list-typeahead could you help me with this question? haha :X

Comment: @HangulSR please accept this answer, if this answer solved your problem, before seeking help on other questions

Comment: Right, i forgot about it. Accepted